# Most current way to reuse server and client side code with node.js and react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently working on a real time multiplayer game, so I want to have the game engine code on the server and the client through a shared folder.

But react uses different syntax to export modules than node.js does.

React is just export as node.js is module.export

would it be smart to do an if statement at the end of each file?

```
if(module.exports === undefined){
     export deafult class/function
} else {
     module.exports = class/function
}
```

Comment: Use babel on your code to transpile it in a standard version that will work with the browsers for the frontend and with node.js for the backend. Your build probably already use that to prepare the JS bundle, you just have to do the same for the server build, to use a code that will be compliant with node.

Comment: Any sources to help me figure that out? I have a limited knowledge with babel.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/ in your scripts that build your project, use babel like that for instance `babel src --out-dir build` and when you start your node instance, do `node build/index.js` instead of `node src/index.js`. You should try it out, it's actually pretty simple!

Comment: Yeah I do that..But how would that detect the shared folder and convert it into a folder the client can use as well as the server?

Comment: You don't have to detect it: babel will rewrite all the exports to be sure it will work. It already does that for your React code, because a browser cannot understand JSX for instance. Neither it can understand import/export modules: babel rewrites the UMD import/export automatically. Nowadays, it fully packaged by utilities like create-react-app, but you can do that full-manual with Babel!